# density function of $W = X^2$ when $X$ is uniform with disjoint intervals

Tags: probability

I'm having some trouble figuring out this (admittedly) very easy problem. Hoping ya'll could help me figure out where I'm going wrong:

> Let $X$ be uniform on $(-2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ and derive the density function for $W = X^2$.

my reasoning goes like this:

$f_X(t) = 1/2$

for $-2\le t \le -1$ and $1 \le t \le 2$

Therefore, the cumulative distribution function is:

$F_X(t) = \int_{-2}^t{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{t}{2} + 1$ for $-2\le t \le -1$

and

$F_X(t) = \int_{1}^t{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ for $1\le t \le 2$

Therefore, for $W = X^2$:

$F_W(t) = P(W\le t) = P(X^2\le t) = P(-\sqrt{t}\le X \le \sqrt{t}) = F_X(\sqrt{t}) - F_X(-\sqrt{t})$

since $F_X(t) = -1 - \frac{t}{2}$ for negative t and $F_X(t) = \frac{t}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$ for positive t:

$F_W(t) = \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{t}}{2} - 1 = \sqrt{t} - \frac{3}{2}$

for $1 \le \sqrt{t} \le 2$ or $1 \le t \le 4$

now, taking the derivative, I should get the probability density function for W:

$\cfrac{dF_W(t)}{dt} = \cfrac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$

and the integral should give me back the cumulative distribution function:

$F_W(t) = \int_{1}^{t}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}} = \sqrt{t}\biggr\rvert_{1}^{t} = \sqrt{t} - 1 $

Which is different from the first evaluation of $F_W$. Obviously the second one makes more sense (since $F_W$ starts at 0 as it should), but I'm confused why I'm getting a different cumulative distribution before differentiating to get the probability distrubtion function and then integrating to get the cumulative distribution function back.

THANKS!

Comment: Note that $F_W$ should increase from $0$ to $1$, so it's your first answer which is wrong. To work out why, I'd recommend noting that your solution for $F_X$ when $-2\le t\le -1$ is decreasing, when it should be increasing, and that your solution for $1\le t\le 2$ starts at $0$ when it should be starting at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Good catch. I think I fixed the problem, but the difference between the two answers is still there.

Comment: Still not quite there - you need $F_X(1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from πr8, here is the answer:

Since the discontinuity makes the second half of the cumulative distribution function start at 1/2, the second cdf should have been:

$F_X(t) = \frac{1}{2}+\int_{1}^{t}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2} + t - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{t}{2}$

The rest of the problem is trivial